# Update Sum Formula to Include Recently Inserted Row Via Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Using a macro, I am inserting a new row at the end of a list of expenses. After the row is inserted, I need the "Total Expenses" cell, which contains a sum formula, to update the cells it's summing together to include the new row that was just inserted. If the row is inserted in the middle of the list, no problem, but if it's inserted as the last expense in the list, the sum formula would need to be updated, and I would like to do this within the macro itself.

I have tried variations on:

```
totalExpense.Formula = "=Sum(D" & ExpensesStart & ":D" & NewExpensesEnd & ")"
as well as:
totalExpense.Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(4, ExpensesStart)), Range(Cells(4, NewExpensesEnd)))

...

Worksheets("Income Statement").Activate

    '[Code to locate the row index of the last "expense" row]

    'Insert Row Above "Total Expenses"
    Rows(count).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
      CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    'Add Name of the Expense
    Range("B" & count).Value = nameValue

    ExpStart = 2
    flag = True

    'Locate row index for start of Expenses
    Do While flag
        'I know it seems weird to immediately add 1, but this is fine
        ExpStart = ExpStart + 1
        If (Range("A" & ExpStart).Value = "Expenses") Then flag = False
    Loop

    'Adjust by 1 row to identify 1st actual expense category
    ExpStart = ExpStart + 1
    totalExpense.Formula = "=Sum(D" & ExpStart & ":D" & NewExpensesEnd & ")"
```

Either I end up with the formula for the cell being **"=Sum(0,0)"** or I just end up with the cell having the value of 0.  Once I was able to get it to properly sum the right range, but instead of leaving the formula **"=Sum(D7:D10)"** it summed the range and left the value.  Given that other values will change after the macro runs, I need the sum formula in that cell, not the sum at the time the macro is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your existing summation range is D7:D10, you could use a summation formula in the worksheet (i.e. not in code) like:

```
=SUM(D7:OFFSET(D11,-1,0))
```

That way, there's no need to change it if you insert a new cell/row before D11.

Comment: This is fantastic, and works beautifully!  Thank you very much!!